# How to get the input value of the cardNumberElement stripe, ONLY IN THE FRONT

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  };
<CardNumberElement
     onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
/>
```

I'm making a nice front for cardNumberElement where the user types the card numbers and they appear on the front like this 1234 **** **** **** 5678 but when I use onChange it returns value as undefined

Answer (score 0):

var cardNumber = document.getElementById('cardNumberElement').value;

Comment: This doesn't work on stripe, this only works for normal input elements or similar components

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the raw card number client-side when using one of Stripe's UI element like CardNumberElement or PaymentElement.

The UI rendered is backed by an iframe hosted on Stripe's own domain and your JS code can't access it. This ensures the data is securely transmitted to Stripe without being accessible by a third-party and is how Stripe ensures you meet the lowest level of PCI Compliance (SAQ A) as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance).

In most cases, you never want to access raw card details yourself since it increases the burden of PCI compliance you have to meet and using Elements or Checkout ensures this is not an issue. If you have to access this information, for example because you store raw card details yourself and meet the higher level of PCI compliance, then you can't use any of Stripe's UI elements and have to build your own form though you lose out on a lot of benefits.

Comment: This is very frustrating, as it makes the form used very difficult to customize, but thanks for the info.

Comment: @RodrigoCarvalho This is for security reasons and as a consumer is a pretty big upside vs any merchant accessing card details whenever they want though. There's a lot you can do to style the different UI Elements That Stripe offers at https://stripe.com/docs/payments/elements There's almost no legit need for you to access the raw card details.